# How to create a table on a linked server with a variable server name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I've seen some solutions on how to create tables on linked servers using `EXEC('some sql') AT [LINKED_SERVER_NAME]` and they work manually.

I can use DML queries such as

```
EXEC ( 'select * from [' + @DbServerName + '].[' + @DbName + '].dbo.someTable' )
```

how can I do something similar for DDL queries like

```
EXEC ( 'CREATE TABLE [' + @DbServerName + '].[' + @DbName + '].dbo.someTable ( id int null) ' )
```

I've toyed around with **select * from openquery(*linkedservername*, query)** and **exec(sql) AT [*linkedservername*]**, but every time I try to make the server name a variable it fails for me.

I can run all these commands manually at in Query Analyzer, but whenever I try to make the linked server name a variable they fail for me.  What I'm trying to do is something like this...

```
DECLARE @LinkedServerName nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @LinkedDbName nvarchar(100)
SET @LinkedServerName = 'SVR2'
SET @LinkedDbName = 'DB2'

DECLARE @DDL_QUERY nvarchar(1000)
SET @DDL_QUERY = 'CREATE TABLE [' + @LinkedDbName + '].dbo.T1 ( id int null )'

-- Current failed ideas
EXEC( @DDL_QUERY ) AT @LinkedServerName
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(@LinkedServerName, @DDL_QUERY)
EXEC( 'CREATE TABLE [' + @LinkedServerName + '].[' + @LinkedDbName + '].dbo.T1( id int null )'
```

Is it possible to dynamically create a table when the linked server name, and database name on that linked server are both declared variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the linked server is also SQL Server (or possibly Sybase):

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @table = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.T1(id INT NULL);';

SET @sql = N'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(@LinkedServerName) + N'.' 
  + QUOTENAME(@LinkedDbName) + N'.sys.sp_executesql @table;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@table NVARCHAR(MAX)', @table;
```

Slightly less verbose syntax:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @exec NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.T1(id INT NULL);';

SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@LinkedServerName) + N'.' 
  + QUOTENAME(@LinkedDbName) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC @exec @sql;
```

Comment: Nesting calls to sp_execsql... very nice.  Thanks!  :-)

Comment: When the LinkedDbName is on EDW environment, how do I set it up?

Comment: @angelcake Like HP EDW? Sorry, no idea. This works because the assumption is that the linked server is also SQL Server. For other platforms, I won't be able to help.

Comment: Yes it is Linux EDW.  it's okay.  Thank you very much!